# How to keep a color in a fill() the same after mousePressed?

Tags: java, processing, fill, rect

What would be the easiest and simplest way to keep the `fill()` the same after clicking (that's when it changes) and then unclicking, and leaving hover?

In this project, I simply made a grid. When the mouse hovers over a specific rect (at `x`,`y`) it changes color based on the state it is in. `fill(50)` is the default, `fill(75)` is when the mouse is hovering, and `fill(100)` is when the mouse clicks. But here when the mouse is unclicked it returns to hover fill until the mouse leaves the rectangle. Thanks.

```
int cols, rows;
int scl = 20;

void setup() {
size(400, 400);
int w = 400;
int h = 400;
cols = w / scl;
rows = h / scl;
}

void draw() {
background(255);

  for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
      int xpos = x*scl;
      int ypos = y*scl;
      stroke(55);
      if((mouseX >= xpos && mouseX <= xpos+scl) &&
        (mouseY >= ypos && mouseY <= ypos+scl)){
        fill(75);
        if (mousePressed == true){
          println("Clicked at: " + xpos + " and " + ypos);
          fill(100);
        //here is the desired location for the fill to remain constant even 
        //after unclicking and leaving hover
        }
        println("Mouse at: " + xpos + " and " + ypos);
      }else{
        fill(50);
      }

      rect(xpos, ypos, scl, scl);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please fix the formatting of your code? You've got two `setup()` functions in there. Also can you please be more specific about exactly what you're trying to do, and which line of code is behaving differently from what you expected?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that! If you run the code now, you'll notice that when you hover over a rectangle it changes color, and when you click it changes color again.

The fill color used after the `mousePressed` is what I want to use to keep the clicked squares their clicked color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. But I'll try to help in a general sense:

You need to store the state of each cell in a data structure, and then use that data structure to draw your scene.

You could do this with a 2D array, where each cell in the array represents a cell in the grid. You could store the state of the cell, or the color directly.

Comment: I'll try something like that, and Processing lets you see the printed array in the console but it always shows something like ``[[I@4e59b084`` and don't know what it means.

EDIT: Also, how could I go about setting up a skeleton for this 2D array?

Comment: @Icy4614 That's because the default behavior is to just print out the hashcode of the array. You might consider writing your own function that prints out the values inside the array, or look for functions in the Java API that might help.

Answer (score 1):

As Kevin said, you should keep the state of your application in a matrix.

```
boolean[][] matrix = new boolean[21][21];
```

When you click on a `cell`, toggle it

```
if(!matrix[xpos/scl][ypos/scl]) {
    matrix[xpos/scl][ypos/scl] = true;
} else {
    matrix[xpos/scl][ypos/scl] = false;
}
```

Inside this loop, check if your current position can be drawn or not

```
if(matrix[x][y]) {
    fill(204, 102, 0); // an orange color
    rect(xpos, ypos, scl, scl);
}
```

So your `draw()` method should look like this

```
void draw() {
    background(255);
    for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
            int xpos = x*scl;
            int ypos = y*scl;

            stroke(55);
            if((mouseX >= xpos && mouseX <= xpos+scl) &&
                    (mouseY >= ypos && mouseY <= ypos+scl)){
                fill(75);
                if (mousePressed == true){
                    println("Clicked at: " + xpos + " and " + ypos);
                    if(!matrix[xpos/scl][ypos/scl]) {
                        matrix[xpos/scl][ypos/scl] = true;
                    } else {
                        matrix[xpos/scl][ypos/scl] = false;
                    }
                    fill(100);
                    //here is the desired location for the fill to remain constant even 
                    //after unclicking and leaving hover
                }
                println("Mouse at: " + xpos + " and " + ypos);
            }else{
                fill(50);
            }
            if(matrix[x][y]) {
                fill(204, 102, 0);
                rect(xpos, ypos, scl, scl);
            }
            rect(xpos, ypos, scl, scl);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Woah! This is just what I needed. Thank you!